# Recuperar datos despues de hacer un append

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Me explico, quiero saber como recuperar los datos insertados dinamicamente con append
Añado el elemento aquí

```
<ul id="playlist"></ul>
```

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
    callback(rawFile.responseText);
  }
 }
 rawFile.send(null);
}
```

jsonfile es el archivo donde se guardan los datos

```
function listAdd(i,json) {
 var dir = json.dir;
 var name = json.name;
 $('#playlist').append('<li data-dir="'+dir+'" id="item'+i+'">'+name+'</li>');
}
readTextFile(jsonfile+".json", function(text){
 var data = JSON.parse(text);
 var total = Object.keys(data).length;
 for (var i=0;i<total;i++) {
  listAdd(i,data[i]);
 }
});
$('#playlist > li').first().data('dir');
$('#playlist').children('li').first().data('dir');
$('#playlist > li:first').data('dir');
$('#playlist > li').length;
```

retornan undefined y 0 por orden

Answer (score 1):

Debes de agregar un div con el id de playlist, el append significa que agregaras un elemento a otro ya existente, en este caso le estas diciendo que le agregaras un elemento li a un div con el id playlist.

```js
let dir = "holis xD";

$('#playlist').append('<li data-dir="'+dir+'">'+name+'</li>');

const a = $('#playlist > li:first').data('dir');
const b = $('#playlist > li:first').data('dir').length;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="playlist"></div>
```

Solo agregando ese codigo bastaria para obtener tando los datos que necesitas del elemento como la longitud del mismo.

Comment: Perdón, es mi primera vez que hago una pregunta aquí y no me dejaba poner todo el código... las variables data y name vienen de un json llamado por otra funcion a ver si puedo variar el código y ponerlo entero, gracias

Comment: De nada @SamuStars si te fue de utilidad la respuesta marcala como correcta cuando puedas :)

Comment: te lo agradezco pero en la constante (a) sigue habiendo "undefined" y en la constante (b) me da error porque no existe

Comment: agrega tu codigo completo de donde te da el error para poder ser mas claro en la respuesta, lamentablemente solo con el codigo que esta no podria darte una respuesta que busques, solo te puedo dar la respuesta en cuanto a lo que veo, la pregunta la puedes editar cuando quieras asi que cuando lo hagas pon un comentario y ya sea yo o el resto de la comunidad te ayudara.